# mysql: count duplicate rows from all the groups

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the follwing table:

```
id  |       fb_id    |   date    | 
----     ----------    ---------     
1         1123           2009-1-1        
2         1145           2009-1-1       
3         1123           2009-1-2        
4         1176           2009-1-2
```

I want to count the total users for each date, the total unique users and the returning users.

My code righte now is this one:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT fb_id) as uniqueUsers, count(fb_id) as totalUsers, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b %y') as zoom  FROM ".PREFIX."zoom GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
Group 2009-1-1:
-total users: 2
-unique users: 2
-returning users:0

Group 2009-1-2:
-total users: 2
-unique users: 1
-returning users:1 (total users - unique users)
```

But instead I am getting:

```
Group 2009-1-1:
-total users: 2
-unique users: 2
-returning users:0

Group 2009-1-2:
-total users: 2
-unique users: 2
-returning users:0 (total users - unique users)
```

Any thoughts how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join. Something like this

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE zoom
    (`id` int, `fb_id` int, `date` datetime);

INSERT INTO zoom
    (`id`, `fb_id`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1123, '2009-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1145, '2009-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1123, '2009-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1176, '2009-01-02 00:00:00');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    count(Znew.fb_id) as totalUsers,
    count(Zold.fb_id) as returningUsers,
    count(Znew.fb_id) - count(Zold.fb_id) as uniqueUsers,
    DATE_FORMAT(Znew.date, '%d %b %y') as zoom
FROM zoom Znew
LEFT JOIN zoom Zold
    ON Zold.date < Znew.date
    AND Zold.fb_id = Znew.fb_id
GROUP BY Znew.date;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b6e4/5)

**Output**

```
totalUsers  returningUsers  uniqueUsers zoom
2   0   2   01 Jan 09
2   1   1   02 Jan 09
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you were doing GROUP BY on YEAR(`date`),MONTH(`date`)etc...
Where you should do on 'DATE(date)' only

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT fb_id) as uniqueUsers,
count(fb_id) as totalUsers,
 DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %b %y') as zoom  FROM ".PREFIX."zoom GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Hope this helps